# Is it possible to have a Css class that acts different in 2 tables

Tags: html, css

I have have two tables `table1` and `table2`.Supposing they are as below:

```
<table id="table1">
<tr>
  <td>Apple</td>
  <td class="special">Banana</td>
 <td><a>Add To Table 2</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Cat</td>
  <td class="special">Mouse</td>
  <td class="special">Banana</td>
  <td><a>Add To Table 2</a></td>
</tr>
</table>

<table id="table2">
</table>
```

Now i have code when we click the `Add To Table` Link this row gets added to table 2 . Now my question is can the class = special be  like , when it is in table 1 it is display:none , and when the row goes in table 2 same class in table 2 becomes display:inline?

Something like:

```
#table1 td .special = hidden
#table2 td .special = visible
```

Not good with CSS so please don't mind the syntax.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I think it would be #table1 tr td.special and #table2 tr td.special = visible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So to be more clear, it would be more:

```
#table1 tr td.special{
   display: none;
} 
#table2 tr td.special{
   display:table-cell;
}
```

EDIT: Look at this http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp

Comment: No problem. Do note what @Jaw.sh said. If you want to hide the table cell from the DOM, use display: none; and for just hiding it from the view use visibility:

My way is just to hide information from prying eyes (but it isn't hard to change to be able to see it).

Comment: No i wanted to save space as the table1 is smaller in width like a shopping cart selection thing when selected i wanted to show with full details something like that.

Comment: Gotcha, I just want to make sure you understand the differences.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is basically correct. You just put a space between td and .special.

```
#table1 .special {
    visibility: hidden;
}

#table2 .special {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

You can also use display:none; to hide elements, but this actually removes them from the DOM (meaning they won't take up space). Setting visibility to hidden simply causes it not to render, but it will take up space in the table as it would if it were visible.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
#table1 tr td.special{
   display: none;
} 

#table2 tr td.special{
   display:block;
}
```